# R - rbind a dataframe with a NULL

Tags: r, null, rbind

I am trying to understand an example from a textbook.

The example code is like this:

```
x <- cbind(x1,x2,x3)
z <- NULL

y <- rbind(z,x)
```

My question is, why did it `rbind` to a `Null` when the output seems same as just `x`?

Comment: It may help to know the broader context of this part of the textbook - what else were they talking about? What were the objects exactly?

As far as I can tell, this doesn't make any sense for the case of a normal data frame. `identical(rbind(NULL, iris), iris) == TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

This example may be to illustrate that `rbind()`ing an object to NULL just returns the non-NULL object. This is something you can make use of if you have code that may or may not return a data.frame/matrix/vector (and otherwise returns NULL). The case you show is fairly trivial, but consider this example:

```r
results <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
  if (i %% 2 == 0) {
    return(data.frame(a = i, b = i / 2))
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
})

# a list of mixed results (some may be NULL)
results
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   a b
#> 1 2 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   a b
#> 1 4 2

# get a data.frame of just the non-NULL rows 
do.call('rbind', results)
#>   a b
#> 1 2 1
#> 2 4 2
```

Here, we are going to iteratively apply `rbind()` to each element in the list resulting from a call to `lapply()`.

The function we apply is arbitrary, but it has some internal logic that leads to a data.frame result, but in other cases returns NULL. Consider for example an API request that may or may not return data, or may or may not be successful if you are not connected to internet.

Since `rbind()` of an object with NULL just returns the original object, there is no additional handling or need to return dummy values for the cases that do not meet the condition.